# Control placeholder image width/height in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, placeholder

I can control the product images **width/height** in `view.xml` located in `app/design/<vendor>/<theme>/etc` in product list page. Some of the products not having images so it tries to show placeholder image. But placeholder **width/height** is not able to control in `view.xml`

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>240</height>
 </image>
<image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
     <width>240</width>
     <height>240</height>
</image>
<image id="product_small_image" type="small_image">
     <width>240</width>
     <height>240</height>
</image>
```

Comment: Try to flush your image cache

Answer (score 3):

The placeholder images will use the same values to resize as the product image do. So the config you provided will also resize the placeholder images.

You have to make sure to add your own placeholder images in Magento's backend at `Configuration> Catalog > Catalog >Product Image Placeholders`. Also remember to re-upload the images in the backend after you change the values in `view.xml`.

Comment: it is not working if we do not upload new placeholder image. we can consider it as bug ?

Comment: Have you tried flushing the images cache via _Flush Catalog Images Cache_ at the Cache Management page in the backend?

Comment: yes.i did that..

Comment: @Stef do you know why you need to "upload the images in the backend after you change the values in view.xml"

Comment: @Stef posted a question on it at https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/189049/6549

Answer (score 0):

Magento's backend at Configuration> Catalog > Catalog >Product Image Placeholders.
There are four options base, small, swatch and thumbnail

I have uploaded resize placeholder image for small option, and its working for listing page properly.