# Magento 2: Product placeholder images cause an exception

Tags: magento2, frontend, placeholder

When I add a view.xml file to my theme I get the following error:

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\NotFoundException):
>   Unable to resolve the source file for
>   'frontend/Holy/mytheme/en_GB/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/.jpg'
>   error message

I can fix it by uploading new [product placeholder images](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-image-placeholders.html) on the Magento admin.

Is there another way to avoid this error?
Why is this error occurring in the first place?

Comment: hope you able to fix this, Would you mind to put answer ? Wondering I've same issue with 2.3 version also :(

Comment: It's a while back but I think this issue can also be fixed by adding the placeholder image to your theme, using a path to override it

Comment: So basically override these files https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/a3c2af0498d21e3f689bc8dd690d7c633a025276/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/base/web/images/product/placeholder in your theme

Comment: No luck facing this in 2.3.3 :(

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to add the requested image-format to my theme's **view.xml** file, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
        <media>
            <images module="Magento_Catalog">
                <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
                    <width>140</width>
                    <height>140</height>
                </image>
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue using below solution:

Please inject

```
\Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation,

$sku = "my-sku";
// get the store ID from somewhere (maybe a specific store?)
$storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
// emulate the frontend environment
$this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
// load the product however you want
$product = $this->productRepositoryFactory->create()->get($sku);
// now the image helper will get the correct URL with the frontend environment emulated
$imageUrl = $this->imageHelperFactory->create()
  ->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->getUrl();
// end emulation
$this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```